# learn to do something vs learn how to do something

Tags: grammar, difference

> it is evident that everybody has some kind of philosophy, even though
> he has never **learned to discuss it**. Everybody is influenced by
> philosophical views, even though he has not thought them out for
> himself and cannot formulate them.

[Materialism and the Dialectical Method - Maurice Cornforth]

I am so confused the use of "learned to discuss it".

How should I understand it?

Learned some kind of philosophy to discuss it

or

Learn how to discuss some kind of philosophy?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title - in everyday use, there is very little difference, and they would be used interchangeably without too much consideration.

To consider the difference critically - if you read a recipe you could probably say "I learned **how** to make [x]". But until you actually put the knowledge to practice, you haven't actually learned to cook it. 'How' to do something is the theory or method.

Regarding your quotation - it is showing that *discussing* philosophy is a learned skill. It makes the point that, while philosophy itself is something that can be studied, everybody has a personal philosophy whether they realise it or not, but may not have the skill to discuss it.

Comment: Thank you! Very clearly!!!!